In Python, how do I pass local variable values to multiprocessing library's Pool?
I struggle with using the multiprocessing library in Python, where I want to use Pool.
Sample code (actual code is far more complex, but would not be helpful in demonstrating the problem):
def Multicore_Patterns_List_processor(Variable1, Variable2, Variable3):
    print(f"Variable1 = {Variable1}, Variable2 = {Variable2}, Variable3 = {Variable3}, current pattern is {Pattern}")

Variable1 = 1
Variable2 = 2
Variable3 = 3
MultiCores = 3
Paterns_list = list(range(1, 21))
with Pool(processes=MultiCores) as pool:
   pool.imap(Multicore_Patterns_List_processor(Variable1=Variable1, Variable2=Variable2, Variable3=Variable3), Paterns_list)

What should the code do:

The code should hand over all variables and the pattern selected (but I don't know how to do it)
There is no need to change the values of Variable1, etc. as these are in the example used to demonstrate a need to transfer some variables to each call
Why Pool? Because, in the actual code, I also use variables for different processes that select the number of processors dynamically

Thank you for any help
Jan Vaško
Note: The expectation is that each function call will work with the variables passed and also the iterator used for multiprocessing.

The first parameter to imap() needs to be a function. You are passing None - i.e., the result of calling Multicore_Patterns_List_processor(). Also, your code is invalid because the variable Pattern doesn't exist

There are several ways to achieve your objective. If you want to use imap() then you could do it like this:
from multiprocessing import Pool

def Multicore_Patterns_List_processor(args):
    Variable1, Variable2, Variable3, Pattern = args
    print(f"{Variable1=}, {Variable2=}, {Variable3=}, current pattern is {Pattern}")

def genargs(Variable1, Variable2, Variable3):
    for p in range(10):
        yield Variable1, Variable2, Variable3, p

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Variable1 = 1
    Variable2 = 2
    Variable3 = 3
    MultiCores = 3
    with Pool(processes=MultiCores) as pool:
        pool.imap(Multicore_Patterns_List_processor, genargs(Variable1, Variable2, Variable3))
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

Output:
Variable1=1, Variable2=2, Variable3=3, current pattern is 0
Variable1=1, Variable2=2, Variable3=3, current pattern is 1
Variable1=1, Variable2=2, Variable3=3, current pattern is 2
Variable1=1, Variable2=2, Variable3=3, current pattern is 3
Variable1=1, Variable2=2, Variable3=3, current pattern is 4
Variable1=1, Variable2=2, Variable3=3, current pattern is 5
Variable1=1, Variable2=2, Variable3=3, current pattern is 6
Variable1=1, Variable2=2, Variable3=3, current pattern is 7
Variable1=1, Variable2=2, Variable3=3, current pattern is 8
Variable1=1, Variable2=2, Variable3=3, current pattern is 9

